# Update Table records ignoring duplicates

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like so:

```
id | name | xyID
----------------
1  | xxx  | 100
2  | yyy  | 200
3  | zzz  | 300
4  | zzz  | 200
```

I need to update all items that are in xyID 200 to now be in xyID = 300 but i have a key on name and xyID so in this case yyy would become 300 but i need to exclude zzz since it would be a duplicate. is there a way i can just ignore duplicates? I suppose i could do this with a script, and select all the items in the previous group and then only update them if they don't exist, but was hoping to just to it in one nice query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will `update` 'yyy' but not 'zzz' by using `not exists()` as part of the `where` clause to make sure that a row with the same `name` that already has a record for `xyId = 300` does not exist.

```
update t
  set xyId = 300
where xyId = 200
  and not exists (
    select 1 
    from t as i
    where i.name = t.name
      and i.xyId = 300
      );
```

If you wanted to `delete` rows with `xyId = 200` that have a corresponding record with `xyId = 300` you could use `exists()` like so:

```
delete
from t
where xyId = 200
  and exists (
    select 1
    from t as i
    where i.name = t.name
      and i.xyId = 300
      );
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/IIQL1351

results from the update:

```
+----+------+------+
| id | name | xyId |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | xxx  |  100 |
|  2 | yyy  |  300 |
|  3 | zzz  |  300 |
|  4 | zzz  |  200 |
+----+------+------+
```

results from the delete:

```
+----+------+------+
| id | name | xyId |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | xxx  |  100 |
|  2 | yyy  |  300 |
|  3 | zzz  |  300 |
+----+------+------+
```

Comment: hmm im getting zero rows updated.. it seems like your logic is correct though.

Comment: @user1336827 I had a typo in my query, sorry about that